# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: while getting the string from SOAP Object(KSOAP2)

Tags: android, soap

I want to get the values from the SOAPObject, as below

```
   anyType{
        Message=anyType{}; 
        ErrorCode=NoError; 
        ImageStatus=anyType{
            ImageTicket=34320146-2035-461c-abd5-d0cba4ebdd37;   
            CustomerImageId=0584e8b766a4de2177f9ed11d1587f55-1; 
            ProductId=anyType{}; 
            StatusName=New images; 
            StatusId=10; 
            IsPaid=false; 
            ThumbnailImageURL=anyType{}; 
            FinalImagesURL=anyType{
                string=anyType{}; 
              }; 
         }; 
    };
```

And i write the code to get the values

```
 SoapObject resultBody = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

 for (int i = 0; i < resultBody.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

    SoapObject body = (SoapObject) resultBody.getProperty(i);

    customerImageId = body.getProperty("CustomerImageId").toString();// throwing exception
    Constants.StatusId = body.getProperty("StatusId").toString();
    thumbnailImageURL = body.getProperty("ThumbnailImageURL").toString();
    isPaid = body.getProperty("IsPaid").toString();

 }
```

And its giving me an exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: CustomerImageId

can anyone help me?

Comment: *I want to get the values from the SOAPObject, as below* ... then you have to start thinking ... error is obvious ... object stored in `body` has no `"CustomerImageId"` property ... now analyze your code to get know why

Comment: @Selvin You're comment is very useful all time.

Answer (score 0):

`CustomerImageId`,`StatusId`, etc are children of `ImageStatus`, not direct property of `anyType`. So access these via object of `ImageStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply @Selvin

My final code is

```
SoapObject resultBody = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

SoapObject body = (SoapObject) resultBody.getProperty(0);

SoapObject statusObject = (SoapObject) body.getProperty("ImageStatus");// added this
customerImageId = body.getProperty("CustomerImageId").toString(); exception
Constants.StatusId = body.getProperty("StatusId").toString();
thumbnailImageURL = body.getProperty("ThumbnailImageURL").toString();
isPaid = body.getProperty("IsPaid").toString();
```

Comment: still, i think you should remove the loop ... and replace it with simple get property `0` or by name - `"GetImageStatusResult"`

Comment: i think you've to use statusObject  instead of body when you want to get value of "CustomerImageId", "StatusId", etc.
like
customerImageId = statusObject .getProperty("CustomerImageId").toString(); //exception

Check this one