# Get property childs in SOAP object in android studio

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I was getting this error when i try to get Propertys from an envelope:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: Codigo
```

But i have this property and it is correctly, see below request from SoapUI:

```
<CalcPrecoPrazoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <CalcPrecoPrazoResult>
        <Servicos>
           <cServico>
              <Codigo>40010</Codigo>
              <Valor>17,20</Valor>
              <PrazoEntrega>1</PrazoEntrega>
              <ValorMaoPropria>0,00</ValorMaoPropria>
              <ValorAvisoRecebimento>0,00</ValorAvisoRecebimento>
              <ValorValorDeclarado>0,00</ValorValorDeclarado>
              <EntregaDomiciliar>S</EntregaDomiciliar>
              <EntregaSabado>S</EntregaSabado>
              <Erro>0</Erro>
              <MsgErro/>
              <ValorSemAdicionais>17,20</ValorSemAdicionais>
              <obsFim/>
           </cServico>
        </Servicos>
     </CalcPrecoPrazoResult>
  </CalcPrecoPrazoResponse>
```

This is my try to get these values

```
try {
        http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        frt = new Frete();

        frt.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("Codigo").toString()));
        frt.setValor(resposta.getProperty("Valor").toString());
        frt.setPrazoEntrega(resposta.getProperty("PrazoEntrega").toString());
        frt.setValorMaoPropria(resposta.getProperty("ValorMaoPropria").toString());
        frt.setValorAvisoRecebimento(resposta.getProperty("ValorAvisoRecebimento").toString());
        frt.setEntregaDomiciliar(resposta.getProperty("EntregaDomiciliar").toString());
        frt.setEntregaSabado(resposta.getProperty("EntregaSabado").toString());
        frt.setErro(resposta.getProperty("Erro").toString());
        frt.setMsgErro(resposta.getProperty("MsgErro").toString());
        frt.setValorSemAdicionais(resposta.getProperty("ValorSemAdicionais").toString())
        frt.setObsFim(resposta.getProperty("ObsFim").toString());


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

And this is the response on android studio when i calling the webservice with an String[] return

```
anyType{cServico=anyType{Codigo=40010; Valor=1720; PrazoEntrega=1; ValorMaoPropria=000; ValorAvisoRecebimento=000;
        ValorValorDeclarado=000; EntregaDomiciliar=S; EntregaSabado=S;
        Erro=0; MsgErro=anyType{}; ValorSemAdicionais=1720; obsFim=anyType{}; }; }
```

I have tryed this solution but this not worked for me...
[Android java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: while getting the string from SOAP Object(KSOAP2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167100/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-illegal-property-while-getting-the-string-f)

PS:I'm using KSoap2 lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Codigo`,`Valor` and other properties are children of `Servicos` and not direct property of `anyType`. So access these via chain of objects of `Servicos` and `cServico` as follows:

```
SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; 
SoapObject body = (SoapObject) resposta.getProperty(0); 
SoapObject subResposta = (SoapObject) body.getProperty("Servicos"); 
SoapObject subRespostaDois = (SoapObject) subResposta.getProperty("cServico");
```

Only then use `subRespostaDois` to access soap message properties:

```
frt = new Frete();
frt.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(subRespostaDois.getProperty("Codigo").toString()));
frt.setValor(subRespostaDois.getProperty("Valor").toString());
```